# Angularjs laravel 5 posting form data using post method 404 page not found error. But get method works

Tags: angularjs, laravel, laravel-5.1

Using Angularjs laravel 5.1 posting form data using post method 404 error comes
but get method works fine

controller

```
(function (ng, app) {
  app.controller('app.promocodeCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
    // create a message to display in our view

    $scope.newPromocode = function () {
      $scope.onSubmit = function () {
        console.log($scope.form);
        // $http.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8';
        //$http.defaults.headers.post["Content-Type"] = "text/plain";
        var request = $http({
          method: "POST",
          url: "backend/statistics/promo",
          data: {
            promocode: $scope.form.codetxt,
            discount: $scope.form.discount,
            minvalue: $scope.form.minvalue
          },
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
          }
        }).success(function (data) {
          alert(data);
        });
      }
    };
  });
})(angular, angular.module('app'));
```

route

`Route::post('statistics/promo', ['uses' => 'Api\Backend\Statistics@promoCode']);`

Comment: Provide code and more details about your question

Comment: are you using same url for both message?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please consult the following: **[How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)**. Your question lacks the necessary details to be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure url used by Angular and route definition for backend are same. It appears that url used in Angular is not defined as a proper route in laravel.
/api/backend or /backend try to hit the angular url in browser and check what response you are getting.